# Creating a grid of images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to web programming and jQuery. I want to load images and arrange them in a grid. However, the number of images to be loaded is not fixed. I have an array, img_arr, with the url and an id for each image.

The code that loads and positions images is like this:

```
var t = 0;
var l = 0;
for (i = 0; i < img_arr.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img)
        .attr('src', img_arr[i]['url'])
        .attr('id',  img_arr[i]['id'])
        .load(function(){
            $('#container').append( $(this) );
            // Your other custom code
            $(this).css( {
                "position": "absolute",
                     "top": t + 'px',
                    "left": l + 'px'
            });
        });
    l = l + 50;
    if (l > 300) {
        t = t + 50;
        l = 0;
    }
}
```

But, the images get placed on top of each other at the final offset location. Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mwahaha! [Evil laughter]

There's an error here, a common, insidious error, one that has nothing to do with images, or CSS, or jQuery.  It's the late-binding error in Javascript.

The OP uses the variables `t` and `l` to mean "top" and "left" (incidentally, OP, what is wrong with `top` and `left` as variable names), incrementing them in a loop and invoking them at a callback.  But `t` and `l` are **late bound**.  When the onload functions are called, those variables are set to their *final* values, not the values they had when the image tag was created.

And so, "the images get placed on top of each other at the final offset location".

Try this:

```
var renderImage = function(imgdesc, t, l) {
   var img = new Image();
    $(img)
        .attr('src', imgdesc['url'])
        .attr('id',  imgdesc['id'])
        .load(function(){
            $('#container').append( $(this) );
            // Your other custom code
            $(this).css( {
                "position": "absolute",
                     "top": t + 'px',
                    "left": l + 'px'
            });
        });
};

var t = 0;
var l = 0;
for (i = 0; i < img_arr.length; i++) {
    renderImage(img_arr[i], t, l)
    l = l + 50;
    if (l > 300) {
        t = t + 50;
        l = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes much more sense now. Looks like I just got trapped in one of the biggest javascript bigfalls. Much thanks, Malvolio.

Comment: @Alvin -- I've been writing Javascript for 15 years and I still do this about once a month.  Of course, I might just be stupid.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't **NEED** to position them absolutely, you could use a flow layout to accomplish this much more easily.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GK8G5/6/) for an example. If you change the CSS for the width of `#container` you will see the number of images in each row change dynamically. I think this is a much cleaner approach. It takes all the math out and lets the browser handle laying things out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why they wouldn't fold properly actually. I'm pretty sure there are some nifty css-tricks you could use to set those positions in a css-file, but let's work with your sample.

Could it be that the container isn't tall enough to contain the additional rows and thusly just place it at the end?

As for your sample, I'd place the math inline, and for 6 images pr row simply do the following instead of using all those counting variables:

```
$(this).css( {
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": Math.floor(i / 6) * 50 + 'px',
    "left": (i % 6) * 50 + 'px'
});
```

It probably won't solve your problem, but it looks cleaner to my eye.

Comment: Note that the `css()` method doesn't need to have `'px'` added to the values passed into properties that take a number. Pixels are the default.

Comment: Fair point artlung. I didn't think about them though, tbh, as my snippet is just a copy-paste with the int-calculations replaced. What a pitty I didn't notice the late binding stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Lots of little inefficiencies in your code. For one use your jQuery, no need to do `new Image()` when you can just do `$('<img />')`. Also, probably at some point someone will want to change the number of images across, or the height of the images, give yourself an out there. Also, you can set multiple tag attributes at once using `.attr({ ... })`, and remember that jQuery comes with the very nice `.each()` method for dealing with regular arrays.

So here's my solution:

```
var numberAcross = 6,
    widthOfImages = heightOfImages = 50;

$.each(img_arr, function(idx, value){
    $('<img />').attr({
        'src': value.url,
        'id': value.id,
        'width': widthOfImages,
        'height': heightOfImages
    }).css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top':  Math.floor(idx  / numberAcross) * heightOfImages,
        'left': (idx * widthOfImages) % (numberAcross * widthOfImages)
    }).appendTo('#container');
});
```

Also, you might want to add css to your `#container` element so you can see a bit better while developing:

```
<style>
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

Note that the `position: relative` in there means that wherever you put that "container" your absolutely positioned items will appear correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips artlung. Very helpful.

Comment: Great! Please vote up any answers that were helpful to you, and when you're satisfied, choose an answer as "best answer" by marking the checkmark.

Comment: "Lots of little inefficiencies in your code."  As Knuth says, "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time."  In particular, the `new Image()` / `$(<img>)` is just a completely random preference.

Comment: Sure. `var img = new Image();$(img)` vs `$('<img/>')`. Is calling the former an inefficiency overstating the case? Maybe. But it feels crufty to me. We're creating a variable we don't need, when we can do it all using a single call to the jQuery API. I know which one I prefer, but I will acknowledge the Perl motto **TMTOWTDI**.