# Showing grid of images with thumnail sized photos

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement where I have to show a grid that contains thumbnail sized photos in say 2 rows and 5 columns. If there are more images, I need some scroller to show rest of images. Now, these are user uploaded images that could vary in size.

Can someone throw some light how can I dynamically resize each image to a thumbnail size and display them in a grid fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would use, or borrow heavily, one of the many ones that are already available for free, or very little money...like those found here:

http://ibrandstudio.com/inspiration/30-best-jquery-image-gallery-plugins-portfolio-website

No sense reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I did see couple of these. But, they all have static images. How can I replace them to use dynamic images instead?

Comment: As the page loads, your code needs to add the images/links to the page, ether by reading from a databse or scanning a directory, whatever the case may be; for example in asp.net in the page_load function you would generated the list of images, and then the jquery gallery scripts would use that list of images that you page_load functionality put on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are two different questions in one. )

To make thumbnails from the user uploaded pictures, you can either use [PHP GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functions - or ready-made PHP scripts, like [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/).

To organize these files into grid, you can use advices given in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014114/creating-a-grid-of-images-with-jquery).